# Has Minecraft mob spawning been changed to reduce effectiveness of vanilla mob farms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built the Minecraft mob farm as shown in

and it doesn't seem to work at all well on my 1.8 server. If I sit in the AFK area, I don't get any mobs. I'm using the layout shown in this diagram (see top left option):

[image: this diagram] and of course, I've lit up all the caves and there are no spawn-able areas other than inside the spawner itself.

The weird thing is, if I go away from the mob spawner and then come back and run rings around it, going from the bottom to the top, then it seems to spawn loads of mobs all of a sudden and then stops again. Why am I not being showered with tons of mob drops?

I don't think it's any kind of 'mob cap' - as I've seen suggested elsewhere, I'm the only person on the server. I have some hoppers and maybe 30 or so mobs (farm animals, villagers, etc) in my 'spawn chunks' (chunks around the map's spawn point) though - might this be causing mobs to spawn in those chunks even when I'm not there and reaching the mob cap? I didn't think mobs would spawn unless they're within 256 of the player.

Has Mojang nerfed these sorts of grinders?

Comment: Wait.. Are you standing **above** (the area where mobs are meant to spawn) or **below** (the area where the mobs die) the spawner area?

Comment: 'Has Mojang nerfed these sorts of grinders?' No, Mojang has not, it was **MICROSOFT!** Also video broken or what ever it is? And I do not think they did nerf it.

Comment: I'm following the advice in the top left diagram and standing below the spawn areas, where it says 'player @'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A friend on mine did a little digging and stumbled on the answer. There's a bug that causes mob spawning to stop if you set the server-side chunk distance to lower than 10.

https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-42053

Solution: set it to 10 or above.

Problem solved. No great M$ conspiracy.

Answer (score 0):

No Changes to mob spawning happend in 1.8, im not sure why yours isnt working but this is what i can tell you. These are all the changes that did happen in 1.8

Minecraft 1.8 - The Bountiful Update

- Added Granite, Andesite, and Diorite stone blocks, with smooth versions
- Added Slime Block
- Added Iron Trapdoor
- Added Prismarine and Sea Lantern blocks
- Added the Ocean Monument
- Added Red Sandstone
- Added Banners
- Added Armor Stands
- Added Coarse Dirt (dirt where grass won’t grow)
- Added Guardian mobs, with item drops
- Added Endermite mob
- Added Rabbits, with item drops
- Added Mutton and Cooked Mutton
- Villagers will harvest crops and plant new ones
- Mossy Cobblestone and Mossy Stone Bricks are now craftable
- Chiseled Stone Bricks are now craftable
- Doors and fences now come in all wood type variants
- Sponge block has regained its water-absorbing ability and becomes wet
- Added a spectator game mode (game mode 3)
- Added one new achievement
- Added “Customized” world type
- Added hidden “Debug Mode” world type
- Worlds can now have a world barrier
- Added @e target selector for Command Blocks
- Added /blockdata command
- Added /clone command
- Added /execute command
- Added /fill command
- Added /particle command
- Added /testforblocks command
- Added /title command
- Added /trigger command
- Added /worldborder command
- Added /stats command
- Containers can be locked in custom maps by using the “Lock” data tag
- Added logAdminCommands, showDeathMessages, reducedDebugInfo, sendCommandFeedback, and randomTickSpeed game rules
- Added three new statistics
- Player skins can now have double layers across the whole model, and left/right arms/legs can be edited independently
- Added a new player model with smaller arms, and a new player skin called Alex?
- Added options for configuring what pieces of the skin that are visible
- Blocks can now have custom visual variations in the resource packs
- Minecraft Realms now has an activity chart, so you can see who has been online
- Minecraft Realms now lets you upload your maps
- Difficulty setting is saved per world, and can be locked if wanted
- Enchanting has been redone, now costs lapis lazuli in addition to enchantment levels
- Villager trading has been rebalanced
- Anvil repairing has been rebalanced
- Considerable faster client-side performance
- Max render distance has been increased to 32 chunks (512 blocks)
- Adventure mode now prevents you from destroying blocks, unless your items have the CanDestroy data tag
- Resource packs can now also define the shape of blocks and items, and not just their textures
- Scoreboards have been given a lot of new features
- Tweaked the F3 debug screen
- Block ID numbers (such as 1 for stone), are being replaced by ID names (such as minecraft:stone)
- Server list has been improved
- A few minor changes to village and temple generation
- Mob heads for players now show both skin layers
- Buttons can now be placed on the ceiling
- Lots and lots of other changes
- LOTS AND LOTS of other changes
- Removed Herobrine

Comment: A link to the official changes list would suffice, what I was asking was had they changed something but not told us, somewhere along the way, for whatever reason? EDIT: 'LOTS AND LOTS of other changes' - doesn't inspire confidence.